# Является ли действительно багом ручной перенос COOKIES из браузера в браузер

Tags: browsers, cookie

*Собственно сабж*.

Сразу оговорюсь что речь не идет о краже `cookies`, XSS и т.д. А конкретно о том что - допустим я скопировал куки из Opera в FireFox и вуаля, я авторизован на сайте.

На этой основе видел на ютюбе кучу примеров авторизации на сайтах к примеру таких как Gmail, Вконтакте и т.д. Где авторы роликов гордо заявляли что это взлом ;)

Вот хочу знать мнение общества, является ли выше описанное багом как таковым?

З.Ы. Возможны примеры, советы, прочее...

Comment: Если в хэше авторизации не присутствует юзерагент, у меня плохие новости для gmail'а ))

Comment: @Sh4dow датирование ролика не знаю, по этому не стОит трубить =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это не баг и не взлом. Но переносить можно не больше трех раз, потом данные становятся некорректными.

Comment: Кстати про ограниченное количество раз не знал!) Видимо больше раз не использовал)